# Find the more appropriate fit by using term.plot in GAMLSS

Tags: gamlss

I'm comparing several GAMLSS models and was wondering how I might use the term.plot to identify the best model/fit. What type of information can we get from this graph? Can I argue that the model with a wider confidence interval performs worse (just looking at this plot, how do you determine on the model's performance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the best model can be

(i) by choosing the fitted model with lowest generalized Akaike information criterion GAIC(k) for a user chosen penalty k for each effective degree of freedom in the model.
[e.g k=2 for AIC or k=log(n) for BIC,
although I prefer k=4 for a Chi-squared test (Chi-Sq with 1 df at 5% =3.84, approx 4]

(ii) looking at the residual (multiple) worm plots and Q-statistics.
This especially highlights problems in the tails of the fitted models.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply. I made the question more clear here,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601860/how-to-find-the-appropriate-model-to-apply-gamlss
 so I would be so thankful if you share your thouth with me regarding the question. I am using GAMLSS to calculate the centile curves based on LMS method including two independent variables. For the several dependent variables, the worm plots look fine but not the Q-statitics (as there are the Z-score >2)